# Robocraft and the Steam Overlay

Tags: steam, robocraft

So I have 95 hours of robocraft playtime. Ever since EAC appeared I have not been able to use the Shift+Tab Steam overlay. I have made a disscusion on the forums and noone seems to be having the problem or knows how to fix it. Maybe someone here does know whats going on and knows how to fix it? I have sent a email to FreeJam about this and no response from them either. I want to get the new robots, it helps support FreeJam. Yes, I also hate EAC

Comment: Do you have any modifications to the Steam overlay @Scyther125? (Mine seems to be running fine, even with Overwolf and Raptr overlays on top of the Steam Overlay) | Try reinstalling Steam.

Comment: Also, have you tried closing all other programs in the background? EAC is known to trigger when having specific programs in the background (not limited to code injectors).

Comment: I do not have this issue.

Comment: EAC has been out for a while now and I believe the Steam overlay issues have been fixed.